# Try to perl program using foreach loop and push, but the code can not run

Tags: perl

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47);

sub listprimes {
    my $n = shift;

    my @answer = ();

    foreach $a(@prime) {
        if($a<=$n){push @answer,$a;}

    return @answer;
}

sub random {
    my($a,$b) = @_;
    return int(rand($b-$a+1))+$a;
}

my $a = random(10,50);
my $f = listprimes($a);

print("f\n");
```

I using the foreach loop and push function to write it, but I get the following errors:

```
./listprime: line 3: use: command not found
./listprime: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./listprime: line 5: `my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47);'
```

Please tell me how can correct it.

Comment: Please look at [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What is your desired behavior?

Comment: Brian, please remember to consider accepting the answer that you've found most useful to you as it benefits both you and the community at large. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for more info.

Answer (score 3):

These errors you are receiving aren't produced by `perl`; they are produced by `bash`. This means you're somehow feeding the script to your shell.

Perhaps you need to make the file executable (e.g. `chmod 700 listprime`).

Also make sure `#!` are the very first two characters of the file. (`od -c listprime | head -n 1` should give `0000000 # ! / u s r / b i n / p e r l \n`.)

If all is in order, you can execute the script using `./listprime`.

---

After you fix that problem, you have a number of problems to fix in your program.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;                             +- Always use this as it finds many errors,
use warnings;                         <-+  although it woulnd't have helped you this time.

my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47);

sub listprimes {
    my $max = shift;                  <--- Try to use meaningful names.

    my @answer;                       <--- New arrays are already empty.

    foreach my $prime (@primes) {     <--- @primes was misspelled.
        if($prime<=$max){push @answer,$prime;}
    }                                 <--- This curly was missing. Proper indenting not 
                                           only makes code easier to read; it makes errors
    return @answer;                        like this obvious.
}

sub random {
    my($min,$max) = @_;               <--- Avoid using $a and $b as they are semi-special.
    return int(rand($max-$min+1))+$min;
}

my $max = random(10,50);
my @selected = listprimes($max);      <--- Use an array to store multiple values.

print("@selected\n");                 <--- Sigil was missing.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using prime instead of primes:

```
foreach $a(@prime) {
```

You are missing a closing bracket to the listprimes for loop.  (Before the return statement).

You are print f instead of $f:

```
print("f\n");
```

This should make it "work", although it could be cleaner.

Comment: I changed it, but it is not working too.                                          ./listprime: line 3: use: command not found
./listprime: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./listprime: line 5: `my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47);'

Comment: Sorry you need a bracket at the end of the for loop, not subroutine.

Comment: @Brian, You're somehow feeding the script to your shell. Perhaps you need to make the file executable (e.g. `chmod 700 listprime`)

Comment: I changed all code as you said. when I run the code and it has the same command before

Comment: @Brian, Did you read my comment and do `chmod 700 listprime`? Also make sure the `#!` are the very first two characters of the file.

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT 1

This edit is based on your updated post and listing some the following errors:

```
./listprime: line 3: use: command not found
./listprime: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./listprime: line 5: `my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47)'
```

These errors are produced because you seem to be launching your script as if it were a *shell* script instead of a *Perl* script. For example:

```
➜  /tmp  zsh test.pl
test.pl:2: command not found: use
test.pl:4: command not found: 2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47
test.pl:4: command not found: my
test.pl:6: command not found: sub
test.pl:7: command not found: my
test.pl:11: parse error near `$a'
```

Note that my errors look different because I'm using a the Zsh, whereas you're using Bash, but it's still the same problem. Instead of doing that, you should use the *Perl* interpreter, as follows:

```
➜  /tmp  perl test.pl
12
```

If your script is already executable (use `chmod 755 <filename>` to add execute privileges) then you can launch it as `./script.pl` and the first `#!/usr/bin/perl` line should take care of the rest.

### Original Response

This is a step-by-step explanation of the code issues I found.

### Changes Needed

Your code had several compilation issues and wouldn't even run. Using the command `perl -c <scriptfile>` issued several problems, which you can reproduce and should take the time to understand.

What follows are the problems with your `listprimes` function. Please note the comments I've made in the code below and the `!!-----` tags I've used to mark them:

```
sub listprimes {
        my $n = shift;

        my @answer = ();

        foreach $a (@primes) {   # !!----- the real array name is @primes, in plural
                if( $a<=$n ){ push @answer, $a; }
        }
        return @answer;   # !!---- This return goes outside the if block
}   # !!---- this brace was missing; you closed the loop's body, not the function's
```

In short, you were referencing non-existent variables, had missing braces and other problems. Again, `perl -c filename` will be very helpful to you.

Your `print("f\n");` call at the end needed the variable `$f` to be referenced, so it should be `print("$f\n");`

### Working Code

```
!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;

my @primes =(2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47);

sub listprimes {
        my $n = shift;

        my @answer = ();

        foreach $a (@primes) {
                if( $a<=$n ){ push @answer, $a; }
        }
        return @answer;
}

sub random {
        my($a,$b) = @_;
        return int(rand($b-$a+1))+$a;
}

my $a = random(10, 50);
my $f = listprimes($a);

print("$f\n");
```

Example output

```
➜  /tmp  ./test.pl
10
```

### Additional Suggestions

You should consider using names that are *descriptive* for all variables. Variable names such as `$a` don't provide any information regarding the *contents* of said variable. For example, an array `@strings` that contains names would be better named as `@names` instead (notice the plural form).

Function names with multiple "words" (e.g. `listprimes`) could read better as `get_primes` or `list_primes`. I tend to prefer a verb_object format for function names as it reads more naturally, given the English language's Subject-Verb-Object structure. In other words, for any given script or module considered to be the subject, a function name of `get_primes` reads better than `primes_get` (unless you try to talk like yoda, which other programmers are unlikely to appreciate).

You should take the type into account when deciding between singular or plural names for variables and functions. For example, a *scalar* variable can only hold a single value. Therefore, a singular name (e.g. `$max_count`) is appropriate. On the other hand, an *array* type can hold multiple values, so a plural name (e.g. `@addresses`) is more appropriate.

The same applies to functions. If a function returns a single scalar value, using a singular name (e.g. `get_max_count`) would be good, but if it returns an array (e.g. `get_addresses`), then pluralizing it is better. If you do this consistently, you provide more information to the *users* of *your* code and the world will be a better place :)